# How to remove background noise with DELL UC 150 Headset

Tags: 18.04, dell, microphone, headset

I connected my DELL headset UC 150 with Lenovo E480 Laptop Ubuntu 18.04.

On Windows the sound is clear without any noise. On Ubuntu I have constant background noise, which makes it hard to use it at all.

Is there any configuration to reduce the background noise from the microphone?

Comment: How is it connected? USB, Bluetooth, 3.5 Jack.

Comment: It is connected by USB. The solution appears to be related to load-module module-echo-cancel in pulseaduio

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution here in this blog post:
https://www.informaticar.net/enable-noise-cancellation-in-ubuntu/

Here are the steps:

Make a backup of the config file we are going to edit:

```
sudo cp /etc/pulse/default.pa /etc/pulse/default.pa.bak
```

Now open the file with root permission in a text editor, for example

```
sudoedit /etc/pulse.default.pa
```

At the bottom of the file in the section `###Make some devices default`, add these lines:

```
load-module module-echo-cancel source_name=noechosource sink_name=noechosink
set-default-source noechosource
set-default-sink noechosink
```

The last two lines are optional and may cause noise cancellation on your output device, meaning that sometimes your audio won’t work and you will have to manually switch to output device which has no noise cancellation enabled. You can avoid this by not adding the last two lines.

Now execute

```
pulseaudio -k
```

or reboot.

Then go to **Settings > Sound > Input** and change input to the device that has *(echo cancelled)* at the end of its description.